# R has problems recognizing factor

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 7 columns, the last column being "Yes/No". I want to to a classification analysis on this dataset but when I use read.csv("/path") and summarize the dataset, one of my computers (not both) struggles to recognize which of the columns is numeric and the classifier column is not recognized at all, it just gives back "lenght: 1832, class: character, mode: character). The other computer gives back just regulary "Project_done, Yes: 1000, No;832". Is it a problem with a csv or something else? The solution was to read.csv and the use "colClasses" and attribute every column with a class, but that would be really unconfortable for the next few codes. Is there any explenation for this or solution?

Comment: You are probably running different versions of R. Newer versions of R do not automatically convert character values to factors, you now need to do that manually if you desire.

Comment: thank you for your help! the questions was allready answered elsewhere and that helped a lot.